# Realm plugin is causing 'app:compileInstantrunconfigDebugKotlin' task to fail

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, realm

I have a project that uses the realm db gradle plugin. After adding it in I began to get instantCompile errors.

I turned off instant run in Android Studio but no dice. Ran `./gradlew clean  && ./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace` and this is the output.

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileInstantrunconfigDebugKotlin'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Compilation error. See log for more details
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.processCompilerExitCode(Tasks.kt:217)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:173)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:104)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.execute(Tasks.kt:97)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:245)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:232)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 14 more
```

Here are my gradle files:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.6'
    ext.compat_lib_version = '23.0.1'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases" }
        maven {
            url 'https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/tree/master/maven-repo/com/uphyca/stetho_realm'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.2.2"
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

subprojects { project ->
    if (project.name.endsWith("-schema")) {
        apply plugin: 'com.github.jacobono.jaxb'
        dependencies {
            jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.7-b41'
            jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.7-b41'
            jaxb 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.7'
        }
    }
}

subprojects {
    task listAllDependencies(type: DependencyReportTask){}
}
```

mbta

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties")
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))


android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ninja.carre.mbta"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.1.0-alpha"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            renderscriptDebuggable false
            pseudoLocalesEnabled false
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        maxProcessCount 4
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
    productFlavors {
        instantrunconfig {
            applicationId "ninja.carre.mbta"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    //    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
//    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.2'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.12'
    compile 'org.sqldroid:sqldroid:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.+'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.+'


    compile group: 'com.google.transit', name: 'gtfs-realtime-bindings', version: '0.0.4'

    //gftsToSql Dependencies
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.7.2'
    compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1100-jdbc3'
    compile 'com.googlecode.juniversalchardet:juniversalchardet:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.3'
    // google play libraries
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$compat_lib_version"
    //support libraries
    compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$compat_lib_version"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$compat_lib_version"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$compat_lib_version"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:$compat_lib_version"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$compat_lib_version"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$compat_lib_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.+'
    compile 'com.github.captain-miao:optroundcardview:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:+'
    compile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Is there a way to figure out what exactly went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Considering you use kotlin, I can tell that

```
app:compileInstantrunconfigDebugKotlin
```

You seem to be using instant run, but that doesn't work well with annotation processors at the moment, and it definitely doesn't work well with Realm's Transform gradle task. So you should make sure it is disabled.

And more importantly,

```
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.+'
```

This should be `kapt`

Also, consider not adding the entire play services

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.0'
```

Comment: Realm uses `kapt` in this case (see https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/3754 ). If you'd like to use Java's annotation processor instead of `kapt`, you need to apply `com.neenbedankt.android-apt` and need to use `apt` configuration instead of `annotationProcessor` configuration.